# Are there any full stack server side javascript frameworks available?

Tags: javascript

I see that javascript is becoming more and more practical as a server side language with the advent of node.js and v8. As far as frameworks go, most of what I've seen are minimalistic frameworks. Even [express.js](http://expressjs.com), one of the more promising ones, is a little bare.

Are there any full stack server-side frameworks out there for JS yet?

Comment: There is plenty of middleware for node.js. Do you need more than that?

Comment: Common wisdom is that for general-purpose commercial web server work, node.js is promising but not anywhere close to being robust enough yet. However for less critical stuff it's pretty awesome and a great way to explore possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's RingoJS, the current form of the (surprisingly old) Helma framework. It's a Rhino-based implementation, so you can get whatever you want from the JVM (sort-of a "good news/bad news" joke I guess).

Comment: http://ringojs.org/ and http://www.helma.org/ for the curious who don't want to fire up a search engine.

Comment: Holy moly @jball how lazy are we around here?!?  :-)

Comment: laziness is the first great virtue of a programmer, at least according to the inestimable Wall.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [towerjs](http://towerjs.org/) and [railwayjs](http://railwayjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very powerful webapp stack called ringojs. It is actually a Rhino prompt that you can use to run javascript modules. It is based on Jetty and features a well designed set of modules and a powerful but simple template engine (including inheritence and macros). You can reuse the galaxy of Java libraries out there throught simple Javascript-Java interop. Coming from J2EE development I threw out a lot of ceremony code and configuration - it is very productive, especially tweaking your running webapp throught the prompt